# Emulator doesn't match my activity layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a pretty basic layout within my Activity_Details layout. However, the emulator doesn't show the same as my desired layout and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it

I've tried just using trial and error and finding somewhere that the textViews will stay

I've also tried manually editing the margin size within the XML documentation.

[Edit: I'm using a Relative Layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#646462"
    tools:context=".DetailsActivity">


<!-- _____________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- SECTION HEADER INFORMATION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMakeAndModel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <!-- License Number Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:background="#E6E600"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:fadingEdge=""
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Year Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#052F99"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Vehicle ID Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="94dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:text="Vehicle ID"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Price Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Colour Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
        android:text="Colour"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Number of Doors Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="493dp"
        android:text="Number of Doors"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Transmission Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="409dp"
        android:text="Transmission"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Mileage Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="409dp"
        android:text="Mileage"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Fuel Type Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="314dp"
        android:text="Fuel Type"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Engine Size Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="315dp"
        android:text="Engine Size"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Body Style Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="227dp"
        android:text="BodyStyle"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Condition Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="99dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="225dp"
        android:text="Condition"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <!-- Notes Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:text="Notes"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

<!-- _____________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- GETTER INFORMATION -->

    <!-- Vehicle ID Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewVehicleID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="166dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Price Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="117dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Colour Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewColour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Number of Doors Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNumberDoors"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Transmission Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTransmission"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="324dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Mileage Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMileage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="326dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Fuel Type Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFuelType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="287dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Engine Size Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewEngineSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="291dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Body Style Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewBodyStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="201dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Condition Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCondition"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="113dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="197dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- Notes Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewNotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginStart="174dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you post you layout xml?

Comment: This often happens if you're using `ConstraintLayout` and you haven't actually constrained your views (and are instead relying on the layout preview positions like `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX`).

Comment: this looks alike a `ConstraintLayout` ...which probably should be a `LinearLayout`. impossible to tell unless having seen the `XML` which produces the mess.

Comment: I'm using a relative layout and I have added the XML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="493dp"
```

use position relative views

```
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
```

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#646462"
                tools:context=".DetailsActivity">


    <!-- SECTION HEADER INFORMATION -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewMakeAndModel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"/>

    <!-- License Number Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMakeAndModel"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="#E6E600"
        android:fadingEdge=""
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"/>

    <!-- Year Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMakeAndModel"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="57dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#052F99"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Vehicle ID Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewLicenseNumber"

        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Vehicle ID"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <!-- Price Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewYear"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Price"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>


    <!-- Vehicle ID Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewVehicleID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <!-- Price Information -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed size and margins in `dp` (something like `android:layout_marginStart="174dp"`) and by doing so you are making your layout not responsive to all screen sizes:

Different phones have different screen size and bu using fixed sizes on your view what may look good on one phone will not look good at all on another phone.

If you want to achieve full responsive layout you should use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Here is an example for your wanted layout using `constraintLayout` and some [guidlines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="ford fiesta"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="E VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="A VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="1 VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2 VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView15"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3 VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4 VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView17"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView15"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView15"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="5 VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="B VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="D VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="C VALUE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

**And the result looks like this:**

[image]